# Conveying score in the context of a grading table

Tags: traduction, anglais, france, éducation, belgique

I am wondering how to convey score in the context of a grading table as follows:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Typesetting_exams_in_LaTeX#Grading_table

[image]

My two cents (don't care about the marks):

[image]

According to https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cote/19600, in Belgium, **cote** may be used for sholar grading but I think it is hardly ever used this way in France.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the score fields represent? How are they computed?

Comment: @jlliagre I would assume the score field is the score of each student, the row is empty so it can be filled in.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Yes, the row is empty but that doesn't help to know what it is expected to contain and how it is computed. My first guess was it would be the sum of the points and the bonus points for each question, but then, why would it be left empty in the examples?

Comment: @jlliagre Désolé si je n'étais pas clair. Oui score désigne la somme des points des points et des points bonus obtenus à chaque exo.

Comment: Le score est donc une sorte de "sous-total".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On pourrait alors simplement nommer cette ligne « **Total** », à la manière de la dernière colonne puisque le processus est le même (somme des points obtenus).

« **Score** » peut aussi être utilisé sans choquer en France dans ce contexte.

On pourrait de même retenir « **Note** » comme intitulé, mais dans ce cas, il serait probablement préférable d'indiquer sur combien cette note doit être comprise. C'est encore plus vrai pour les notes apparaissant dans la colonne de droite pour lesquelles on aimerait savoir combien de points ont été accumulés par rapport au nombre de points maximum possibles pour les deux catégories de questions. Sans référence, les notes ont en France tendance à être comprises comme étant sur vingt, ce qui serait trompeur dans cet exemple.

« **Cote** » a de nombreux sens mais n'est plus utilisé en France dans ce contexte.

Answer (score 1):

Dans l'éducation en France, on utilise le généralement mot **note** pour désigner le total de points sur un contrôle. D'ailleurs, l'article du Larousse que tu as cité donne pour un des sens de "cote" :

> En Belgique, **note** scolaire.